# Positional parameters and functions

Tags: linux, function, unix

How do you call a function with a filename parameter (positional parameter $1).
I'm not very good a coding and tried researching it but was not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the right way.

```
Double()
{
     echo "Number is : $(( $1 * 2 ))";
     echo "Text is : $2";
}
```

Example :

```
bash-4.1$ Double 2 Hello
Number is : 4
Text is : Hello
bash-4.1$
```

Hope this sample is good for you. regards!